# ORA-14405 when dropping a tablespace with no data

Tags: oracle, tablespaces

I was cleaning up tablespaces and wanted to delete one, and after moving all the segments from it, I got the following:

```
SCOTT.OE> drop tablespace fact_index including contents and datafiles;
drop tablespace fact_index including contents and datafiles
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14405: partitioned index contains partitions in a different tablespace
```

I tried looking for where all the schemas had data in all tablespaces.  No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at https://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com/2011/04/ora-14404-14405-and-deferred-segment.html -- Summary:  Cause is a feature; if you define a table/index that is partitioned, and used the `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED` option specifying the tablespace you are now attempting to drop, you get that error.

Solution:  Query for the DEF_TABLESPACE_NAME column:

```
SCOTT.OE> select def_tablespace_name from all_part_tables where owner='SCOTT';

DEF_TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
FACT_DATA
FACT_DATA
...
FACT_INDEX2
FACT_INDEX2
FACT_INDEX2
FACT_INDEX2
...
```

And then alter the table definition.